# How to serve static files to Dockerized Angular apps on the same domain using Nginx and Traefik?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, traefik

What I’d like to do is have 2 Angular apps on the same domain, but serve different files for different paths. For example, browsing to “app1/” will show different content than that on the “app1/test” path. Note: these are default Angular apps, they’re not doing anything special. The only thing I’ve changed the landing page to say “app1” or “app2” to verify that paths hit the correct container.

Additionally, I want anything on the app1/test path to resolve to the same host. So paths like “app1/test” and “app1/test/page1” will lead to the same container. I can get to app1/ with no issues, but I can’t seem to figure out how to route to app1/test correctly. I can browse to it, but it serves the content of app1/ instead of what it’s supposed to. I’ve verified that all of the files I’m creating are inside the container as well, they’re just not being accessed.

Finally, the URL information needs to be in a state that allows nginx to route to the correct container and also allow the angular apps to handle its own virtual routing, without these two interfering with one another.

Here are my config files:

docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  app1:
    build:
      context: ./app1
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.middlewares=app1-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.middlewares=app1-autodetect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app1-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app1-autodetect.contenttype.autodetect=false"
      - "traefik.port=80"

  app2:
    build:
      context: ./app2
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/test{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.middlewares=app2-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.middlewares=app2-autodetect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app2-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/test"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app2-autodetect.contenttype.autodetect=false"
      - "traefik.port=80"
```

Dockerfile for both Angular apps

```
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@11.0.7

# add app
COPY . /app

# generate build
RUN ng build --output-path=dist

# base image
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf for app1

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

nginx.conf for app2

```
include mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /test {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. There were a few edits I made along the road, but the final key to the puzzle was a "try_files" line in my nginx.conf files. Read about it here: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

Here are the updated files:

docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.4"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
  app1:
    build:
      context: ./app1
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.rule=Host(`localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.middlewares=app1-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app1.middlewares=app1-autodetect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app1-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app1-autodetect.contenttype.autodetect=false"
      - "traefik.port=80"

  app2:
    build:
      context: ./app2
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.rule=PathPrefix(`/test{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.middlewares=app2-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.routers.app2.middlewares=app2-autodetect"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app2-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/test"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.app2-autodetect.contenttype.autodetect=false"
      - "traefik.port=80"
```

Dockerfile (for app1)

```
FROM node:14.15.4 as build

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@11.0.7

COPY . /app

RUN ng build --output-path=dist

FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Dockerfile for app2

```
FROM node:14.15.4 as build

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@11.0.7

COPY . /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
RUN ng build --base-href /test --deploy-url /test/ --output-path=dist

FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/test
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.conf for app1

```
include mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf for app2

```
include mime.types;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location /test {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /.ico {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        add_header Content-Type     image/x-icon;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should serve from subdomains which are more easily manageable, there is a general accepted pattern sandbox|dev|test|staging.example.com, example.com being production.
You'd be able to route properly in the whole stack (reverse proxy, web server, angular), drop cookies, manage separate identities etc.

Unfortunatelly what you are experiencing happens because the lack of negation in traefik's routing rules but also in regular expression used to describe the routing. Basically the 1st router is taking over, Host('localhost) in a greedy way.
What you can do is follow Traefik's docs and try to set a priority:

see section Set priorities -- using the File Provider at
https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#priority

Comment: Serving from subdomains is not the question, since this API would be a part of the individual domain - the API and second app should reside within the same domain.  The issue being discussed is what happens when the routing gets routed to the correct container (the chronos container) where the nginx routing is looking for a subfolder rather than letting the firtual routing handle it.

Comment: Have to disagree, the question is about behaviour of traefik which as i explain in the answer, behaves greedly on the setup of the routes:
_I can get to app1/ with no issues, but I can’t seem to figure out how to route to app1/test correctly_

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified that I'm not just a stranger on the internet - we're working together, so I was clarifying the intent behind the question.

Comment: no problem, if you can edit the question with the exact requirements listed a bit different than it is right now, to me it's a bit unclear what is the request flow, i'll take another look and offer a comment